# Phrase for the sickness experienced when once a most favorite perfume or song or food desired feel disgusting after repetitive use/listening

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

What is common phrase or word for the sickness / queasiness we have when once a most favorite perfume we ached for to use or food we long to eat or song we desired to listen to, again and again is lost due to its repetition (repetitive consumption).

While I read about olfactory fatigue but it seems to define as a temporary effect, while the above is more a long term effect. Moreover even if olfactory fatigue is used as long-term term, still there is no common word for such a phenomenon that I know of. The closest term I can come up with is "Repetitive consumption fatigue" but is there any already phrase in use especially when this is a common phenomenon.

Comment: You mean when you are fed up with the perfume, song, etc?

Comment: yes and although there is olfactory fatigue term for perfume or smells, but i am looking for a common phrase for all song, perfume or food and alike.

Comment: The only bit in "olfactory fatigue" that applies to smell is *olfactory*. If you remove it, you will discover the generic term that applies to everything.

Comment: I like *fed up with a song* or *grown tired of a perfume*. These capture a transition in your attitude about the song or perfume.

Comment: There are the odd hits on the internet for "I'm curried out", "I'm sphagettied out", "I'm Beethovened out",  "I'm Dylaned out" ...  ("I'm Brahmsed out of my mind" appears to be a pun).

Answer (score 1):

You could describe it as [being surfeited](https://www.lexico.com/definition/surfeit) with the substance. Lexico defines the verb as

> Cause (someone) to desire no more of something as a result of having consumed or done it to excess.

with the example

> ‘I am surfeited with shopping’

So you could describe yourself as "surfeited with strawberries" or "surfieted with Chanel No5".

Being surfeited is usually a temporary condition but it is possible for the aversion to be permanent.

In Medieval and Renaissance times it was quite common for people to be diagnosed as having "died from a surfeit of something" usually a delicacy. Personally I think these were probably cases of food poisoning diagnosed as a surfeit because the offending item was vomited up before death.

This does lead, however, to Duke Orsino's soliloquy at the start of Shakespeare's Twelfth Night beginning

> If music be the food of love, play on,

> Give me excess of it; that surfeiting,

> The appetite may sicken, and so die.

Twelfth Night Act 1, scene 1, 1–3